# Synchronization between drawcalls in Vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

As far as I understand, if I have a drawcall that in some way uses the results of any previous drawcall or writes to the same render target (framebuffer), then I need to make sure that the later drawcall sees the memory effects of all previous drawcalls.

But what about, when I am rendering a scene with a bunch of objects, each such object is one drawcall and all these drawcalls write to the same framebuffer.

Do I need to issue a memory barrier after every drawcall ?

For example Sascha Willem's pbrbasic example has this code (a bit simplified) and I do not see any pipelines barriers there:

```
VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBeginCommandBuffer(drawCmdBuffers[i], &cmdBufInfo));

vkCmdBeginRenderPass(drawCmdBuffers[i], &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

VkViewport viewport = vks::initializers::viewport((float)width, (float)height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vkCmdSetViewport(drawCmdBuffers[i], 0, 1, &viewport);

VkRect2D scissor = vks::initializers::rect2D(width, height, 0, 0);
vkCmdSetScissor(drawCmdBuffers[i], 0, 1, &scissor);

VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = { 0 };

vkCmdBindPipeline(drawCmdBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(drawCmdBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, NULL);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(drawCmdBuffers[i], VERTEX_BUFFER_BIND_ID, 1, &models.objects[models.objectIndex].vertices.buffer, offsets);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(drawCmdBuffers[i], models.objects[models.objectIndex].indices.buffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);

Material mat = materials[materialIndex];

for (uint32_t y = 0; y < GRID_DIM; y++) {
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < GRID_DIM; x++) {
        glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(float(x - (GRID_DIM / 2.0f)) * 2.5f, 0.0f, float(y - (GRID_DIM / 2.0f)) * 2.5f);
        vkCmdPushConstants(drawCmdBuffers[i], pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0, sizeof(glm::vec3), &pos);
        mat.params.metallic = glm::clamp((float)x / (float)(GRID_DIM - 1), 0.1f, 1.0f);
        mat.params.roughness = glm::clamp((float)y / (float)(GRID_DIM - 1), 0.05f, 1.0f);
        vkCmdPushConstants(drawCmdBuffers[i], pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT, sizeof(glm::vec3), sizeof(Material::PushBlock), &mat);
        vkCmdDrawIndexed(drawCmdBuffers[i], models.objects[models.objectIndex].indexCount, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

drawUI(drawCmdBuffers[i]);

vkCmdEndRenderPass(drawCmdBuffers[i]);

VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkEndCommandBuffer(drawCmdBuffers[i]));
```

Are there any guarantees that drawcalls logically following after will see the memory effects of drawcalls logically before them ?

So the question is, when do I need to synchronize between different drawcalls ?

Comment: Which memory effects do you mean? Executing a draw after another draw is basically Write-After-Write operation and handled by hardware (e.g. depth buffer, blending order). But in the case of the second draw read after the first draw write you need to synchronize somehow (not sure if it possible during the same queue submission).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> uses the results of any previous drawcall or writes to the same render target

Those are *not* the same thing. The side-effects of a rendering operation (stuff you modify via image load/store or SSBOs) and stuff written to the framebuffer have very different needs as far as synchronization is concerned.

The fixed function operations that lead to the writing of a value to the framebuffer (scissor test, depth test, blending, etc) are governed by [rasterization order](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/chap24.html#primrast-order): they must happen atomically and in that particular order, within a given primitive and for a particular sample potentially being written to the frame buffer. And the execution of such operations must also respect [primitive order](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/html/chap19.html#drawing-primitive-order): the order of primitives generated by drawing commands, but also the order of primitives *within* a drawing command.

So as far as rendering is concerned, draw calls will respect the results of previous draw calls, within the same subpass (between subpasses is governed by explicit subpass dependencies). You don't need to do anything special to make blending work. If you have two overlapping triangles, with one happening after the other by primitive order, the second draw's blending will use the results of the first draw. It just works.

Any other writing by your shader requires explicit synchronization.

Comment: So this particular example works because no matter what order you draw the primitives in, the next draw call will use the depth information of the previous draw calls, based upon rasterization order, which is the order the commands were ordered by the user?  What situations if any in a *draw call* would require explicit synchronization?

Comment: Draw access to the framebuffer is synchronized per definition, but access to other targets like textures and storage buffers is not. So when you read from a texture you need to make sure that this texture is not being modified(which usually doesnt happen since textures mostly are static)

Comment: @Dynamitos Thanks!